# Facebook applications and WP7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to perform facebook post into the user wall from wp7 (but **without** using the nice built-in ShareLinkTask of mango, **please don't ask me why**, its a requirement).

So, lets say I must do it as I was in Wp7 before mango, the only way available I found, is based on building a facebook application and using that applicationId with the facebook sdk.

It works but I need to use an ad-hoc or a company account to create the app, I was not able to do both, it seems that comapny account cannot create apps, ad-hoc account are prohibited.

Is there a way to create a facebook app withouth using a personal account ?
Is it really necessary to create a facebook app to make a wp7 app post to facebook (without using the ShareLinkTask of mango).

thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way to post on somebody's wall. You have to use the SDK and to register your app on Facebook because the user has to explicitly authorize your applications to post on his wall.

Even if you post a message from the built-in Windows Phone features, you'll see on Facebook that the message has been posted with the application Windows Phone. And you can retrieve the settings of that application in your facebook account settings:

[image: Windows Phone facebook app settings (in french)]

Comment: Ok, but it seems that facebook allow to create app only to real person. Is that possible ? Its not explicitly state but i was not able to make "create new app" appear on a company account. How company work around that ? Creating an ad-hoc user is prohibited (and they have strong check on that).